# Calling a powershell script from a powercli script using invoke-vmscript?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am attempting to execute a .ps1 on multiple VM's using the invoke-VMScript function. Currently I have the code:
`Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $script -VM $servername -guestcredential $gcred -hostcredential $hcred` and have `$script = 'data.ps1'` however this returns the error stating that 'data.ps1' is not a valid function or script. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try passing the full path to `data.ps1`.  It may be looking for it in a different folder than you think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not set up to test this, but I would guess that `-ScriptText` needs to be given the full path to a .ps1 file accessible on the VM.

```
$script = '"C:\my scripts\data.ps1"'
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $script -VM $servername -guestcredential $gcred -hostcredential $hcred
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in script variable content of your script, not file name.

Comment: Not true.  See http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI51/html/Invoke-VMScript.html: "ScriptText: String: Specify the text of the script you want to run. **You can also pass to this parameter a string variable containing the path to the script.**"

Comment: im pretty sure the string variable though is going to attempt to execute a script located on the guest machine.  in which case, this answer is somewhat correct.